# Can anyone point me to a php-solr precompiled dll?

Tags: php, solr, php-extension

I am using a vc6-x86 version of php and I want to find a precompiled php_solr.dll. Can someone point me where can I get those ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since none of the answers provided me with a viable answer, I installed [php-solr-client](http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/)
That worked good and has a good community support too...

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I think this would help you. http://downloads.php.net/pierre/
You might try upgrading to vc9. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

this dosn't work for me. The error message:"
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files\PHP\ext\php_solr.dll' - is not found specified procedure."  :-(

I have php-5.3.5-Win32-VC9-x86, Apache 2.2

Answer (score 0):

Please use PECL Solr Extension 1.x for Solr Server 3.x, or use PECL Solr 2.x for Solr Server 4.0+

https://pecl.php.net/package/solr/1.1.1/windows

https://pecl.php.net/package/solr/2.1.0/windows